# Authenticate npm private registry in docker

Tags: docker, yarnpkg, npm-registry, yarn-v2, npm-private-modules

We're publishing scoped js packages to a private registry (managed by us using Verdaccio).

It means that in our production environment, we need to authenticate to our private registry to use `yarn install`. What's the easiest way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't or don't want to use `.env` file, but you already have `.yarnrc.yml` file with your registry url like that:

```
npmScopes:
  yourScopeName:
    npmRegistryServer: 'https://...'
```

then you can use `yarn config set` command to add `npmAuthToken` key with your token value, for example:

```
// $REGISTRY_TOKEN is an ARG variable you pass to Docker
ARG REGISTRY_TOKEN

RUN yarn config set 'npmScopes.yourScopeName.npmAuthToken' "$REGISTRY_TOKEN"
```

Comment: That will leak `REGISTRY_TOKEN` on an image layer

Answer (score 0):

## The prettier solution (IMO)

### Switch to yarn berry (yarn v2)

[Migration guide](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration)

### Use environment variables in .yarnrc.yml :

```
yarnPath: ".yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs"
nodeLinker: node-modules
npmScopes:
  customScope:
    npmRegistryServer: ${NPM_REGISTRY}
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmAuthToken: ${NPM_TOKEN}
```

### Set environment variable values

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  server:
    image: node:14
    environment:
      NPM_REGISTRY=https://private-registry
      NPM_TOKEN=PUT_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/app
    command: "yarn run dev"
```

You can also put env vars in a `.env` file and add it to `.gitignore`

### Tests

1. Add a scoped package

   `docker-compose run --rm server yarn add @customScope/test-package`
2. Install

   `docker-compose run --rm server yarn install`